# Selecting rows where some columns are same but others are different

Tags: sql, exists

I have a dataset set up as follows:

| Name | Age | Job | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 20 | Plumber | 01/20 | 08/20 |
| Joe | 20 | Joiner | 08/20 | 09/21 |
| Kevin | 28 | Plumber | 07/20 | 08/20 |
| Kevin | 28 | Plumber | 08/20 | 09/21 |
| Michael | 25 | Plumber | 01/20 | 11/20 |
| Michael | 25 | Joiner | 11/20 | 07/21 |

I'm trying to get all rows where the name and age are the same but the job differs. The output dataset should look like this:

| Name | Age | Job | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 20 | Plumber | 01/20 | 08/20 |
| Joe | 20 | Joiner | 08/20 | 09/21 |
| Michael | 25 | Plumber | 01/20 | 11/20 |
| Michael | 25 | Joiner | 11/20 | 07/21 |

Could someone be able to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a duplicate (name, age) pair `EXISTS` but has different job:

```
SELECT *
FROM t AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM t AS t2
    WHERE t2.name = t1.name
    AND t2.age = t1.age
    AND t2.job <> t1.job
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE AS C
  JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS C2 ON C.Name=C2.Name AND C.Age=C2.Age AND C.Job<>C2.Job
```

Comment: You are correct, but code-only answers tend to be low quality, both for the current user asking the question and for future users with similar issues. An explanation of your solution adds significant value to your answer. (+1 anyway, just for being right.)